# how to create own parameters while using seeding and factory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create four corrals which is default in table. So, it has only id and name. Name of each corral should be "Corral 1", "Corral 2", "Corral 3", "Corral 4". The numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 should be taken from id. I know that I can do in seeds manually, but I want to use factory for more clean code. Now, my factory looks like:

```
$factory->define(App\Corral::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need it once, run the factory 4 times passing the data you need. If you need it often - the easiest option is to create a seeder that creates 4 models and then run it either in your `setUp` method or in your test methods when required.

```
// Seeder
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    factory(Corral::class)->create([
        'id' => $i,
        'name' => "name {$i}",
    ]);
}

// Test
$this->seed(YourCorralSeeder::class);
```

Comment: my factory remains the same?

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov, see no reason to change it.